# Why does jnp.einsum produce a different result from manual looping?

Tags: numpy, jax

Let's say I want to compute an inner product along the last dimension of two matrices

```
a = jax.random.normal(jax.random.PRNGKey(0), shape=(64,16), dtype=jnp.float32)
b = jax.random.normal(jax.random.PRNGKey(1), shape=(64,16), dtype=jnp.float32)
```

I can do it with `jnp.einsum`:

```
inner_prod1 = jnp.einsum('i d, j d -> i j', a, b)
```

or manually call `jnp.dot` in a loop:

```
inner_prod2 = jnp.zeros((64,64))
for i1 in range(64):
  for i2 in range(64):
    inner_prod2 = inner_prod2.at[i1, i2].set(jnp.dot(a[i1], b[i2]))
```

```
print(jnp.amax(inner_prod1 - inner_prod2)) # 0.03830552
```

This is quite a large difference between the two, even if they are mathematically equivalent. What gives?

Comment: I also cannot replicate these results, on Mac using jaxlib0.4.14 or jax-metal 0.0.4. are you using a GPU?

Comment: I was using a TPU, which explains the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All operations in floating point accumulate rounding errors, so in general when you express the same operation in two different ways, you should expect the results to not be bitwise-equivalent.

The magnitude of the difference you're seeing is larger than is typical for float32 precision; it makes me think you're probably running your code on TPU, where matrix multiplication is done at lower-precision by default. You can adjust this using the [`default_matmul_precision`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.default_matmul_precision.html#jax.default_matmul_precision) configuration; for example like this:

```py
with jax.default_matmul_precision('float32'):
  inner_prod1 = jnp.einsum('i d, j d -> i j', a, b)
  inner_prod2 = jnp.zeros((64,64))
  for i1 in range(64):
    for i2 in range(64):
      inner_prod2 = inner_prod2.at[i1, i2].set(jnp.dot(a[i1], b[i2]))
```

If you do the computation this way, I suspect you'll probably see a smaller difference more typical of float32 computations, on order `1E-6` or so.